# How to use destructing in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying about react. When I write code just like this, because of async, console.log doesn't catch input.value correctly. (problem of timing)

```
handleInput = (e) => { 
  this.setState({
   text: e.target.value
  }); 
  console.log(this.state.text); 
}
```

so I fixed it like this, and it works well.

```
handleInput = (e) => { 
  this.setState({
   text: e.target.value
  },
  () => {console.log(this.state.text)}
 );
}
```

Then, I try to destructing like this, but it doesn't work well again.

```
handleInput = (e) => { 
  const {text} = this.state;
  this.setState({
   text: e.target.value
  },
  () => {console.log(text)}
 );
}
```

so I fixed it like this, and it works well. I think this is beacuse of async too, But I'm not sure.

```
handleInput = (e) => {  
  this.setState(
  {
   text: e.target.value
  },
  () => {
   const {text} = this.state;
   console.log(text);
  }
 );
}
```

So my question is, if I want to use destructing in setState(), Do I should write code like that every time? I mean, Always use destructing inside of setState?

Comment: Should I write code like that every time? I mean, Always use destructing inside of setState? -> Yes

Comment: Use `componentDidUpdate` if you want to correctly "log" your state after it's updated. Other than that, use object destructuring where it makes sense for you, it doesn't make sense to ***always*** do it one way or the other. It's an opinionated question/answer. Voting to close as "opinion based".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found on react docs:

setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

This is what you've done in your first fix and It is the right way to do it.

Now in your second problem

```
handleInput = (e) => { 
  const {text} = this.state;
  this.setState({
    text: e.target.value
   },
   () => {console.log(text)}
  );
}
```

You are destructuring in the handleInput method, so the value wont be available to the setState() callback as it wont get executed in the same sequence as you're reading the code.
The way you fixed it should work fine as you're using an arrow function and you wont need to bind "this" to method, so it should have access to same "this" instance.

Now coming to destructuring, its entirely upto you when do you want to use it. It can make your code look cleaner in some cases but not make sense all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really look at this code. You have not destructed the `state` inside the callback of `setState` function.

```
handleInput = (e) => { 
  const {text} = this.state;
  this.setState({
   text: e.target.value
  },
  () => {console.log(text)}
 );
}
```

You have moved it to the callback in below and it worked,

```
handleInput = (e) => {  
  this.setState(
  {
   text: e.target.value
  },
  () => {
   const {text} = this.state;
   console.log(text);
  }
 );
}
```

Hope this clear things out!

Answer (score 1):

The way you've destructured the state in third example, it will get the previous state and not the current state. For getting the state after it has been update you need to use the second callback to `setState` or you can use `componentDidUpdate`.

On a side note you can also destructure the `event` object, as shown below:

```
handleInput = ({ target: { value: text } }) => {
  this.setState({ text }, () => {
    const { text } = this.state;
    console.log(text);
  });
};
```

But destructing isn't always necessary, according to me if it doesn't make the code more readable, maintainable there's no point in using it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to `async`.

You don't have to do [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) that way.
Keep `handleInput` simple.

```
handleInput = (e) => this.setState({text: e.target.value})
```

You can object destructuring anywhere you want.

One of the better ways would be using [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    const prevText = prevState.text
    const {text} = this.state
    console.log(prevText, text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, since setting of the state is an asynchronous task and you need the latest value of the "text" variable after firing the setState function, you will need to destructor its value from inside the callback function.

Whereas if you just need the state value and do not need to update the state before getting that state value, you can destructor the "text" value from anywhere in your code without the need for the callback function.